# Calculating time frame among events in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am a rookie and trying to write a Sql for calculating the time frame between different start date from following table..

```
 ID         StartDate
202151080   3/27/2014 0:00
202151080   5/16/2014 0:00
202151080   10/27/2014 0:00
```

My expected output is

```
 ID         StartDate        interval
202151080   3/27/2014 0:00    0
202151080   5/16/2014 0:00    50
202151080   10/27/2014 0:00   164
```

I can come up for static..like below.. i am struggling for calculating difference from reading table.

```
SELECT id, datediff(dd,'2014-03-27 00:00:00','2014-05-16 00:00:00');
```

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
SELECT ID, StartDate,
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(StartDate, 
                        (SELECT StartDate
                         FROM mytable AS t2
                         WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.StartDate < t1.StartDate
                         ORDER BY StartDate DESC LIMIT 1)), 0) AS `interval`
FROM mytable AS t1                             
ORDER BY StartDate
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db1c4d/1)